# How to make a table of pairs (plot, matrix)?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I am generating a random matrix $F$ and then plotting norm of the matrices $E+Ft$, representing them as a table. But I also want to print the matrix $F$ near every plot. If I remove the semicolon from `F // MatrixForm;` in the code below I get some errors.

My code:

```
Dimension := 3;
Iterations := 2;
Table[
 M = RandomComplex[{0, 20}, {Dimension, Dimension}];
 F = UpperTriangularize[M, 1];
 F // MatrixForm;
 Plot[
    Norm[
    Inverse[IdentityMatrix[Dimension] + t*F]
   ],
    {t, 0, 1}
  ],
 {n, 1, Iterations}
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that?

```
Dimension := 3;
Iterations := 2;
Table[M = RandomComplex[{0, 20}, {Dimension, Dimension}];
  F = UpperTriangularize[M, 1];
 Plot[Norm[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[Dimension] + t*F]], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[MatrixForm[F], Below]], {n, 1, Iterations}]
```

[image]

If you replaced the Placed[..,Below] it is printed next to it.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But is there a way to just print a few things that are inside Table?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann You can use the `Print` statement. Check the documentation for some examples http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap each plot with `Labeled[..., Bottom]`:

```
dimension = 3;
iterations = 2;
M = RandomComplex[{0, 20}, {iterations, dimension, dimension}];
F = UpperTriangularize[#, 1] & /@ M;
Row[Table[Labeled[Plot[Norm[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[dimension] + t*i]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 350], MatrixForm[i], Bottom], {i, F}], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]